# Functions are in intervals of $L^p$ spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

It just occurred to me that a dominated convergence theorem argument proves that $p\mapsto\|f\|_{L^p}$ is continuous, which implies the set of $p$ for which $f\in L^p$ is open. This is shocking to me because it implies if $f$ is in one $L^p$ space then it's in a whole interval of them.

Is this reasoning right? After taking many analysis courses I am surprised to not have encountered this fact. Does anyone know of any other fun consequences of this observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuity of $p \mapsto \|f\|_{L^p(\mu)}$ requires that the measure $\mu$ is finite (as far as I know).

Indeed, if $\mu$ is not finite, e.g. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^+$, you find functions which belong to exactly one $L^p$, e.g.,
$$u(x) = \begin{cases} 0  & x \in [1/2, 2]
 \\ \frac{1}{\log(x) \, \sqrt{x}}  & \text{else} \end{cases}$$
belongs just to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$, but not to any other $L^p(\mathbb{R}^+)$.

**Edit:** Moreover, if $\mu$ is finite, then $f \in L^p(\mu)$ implies $f \in L^q(\mu)$ for all $q \in [1,p]$.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Nice counterexample!

Comment: Comment on your edit: $q\in[1,p+\epsilon]$ yes?

Comment: No. Take the above $u$ on the finite measure space $[0,1/2]$. It is precisely in $L^p(0,1/2)$ for $p  \in [1,2]$.

Comment: I would like to add that for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$, and a function $f\in L^p\cap L^q$ where $1\leq p<q$, the function $s\mapsto \Vert f \Vert_{L^s}$ is actually continuous on $[p,q]$ and even $\mathcal C^1$ on $(p,q)$.